# Add together elements up to certain index

Tags: python

So I have an array `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`
and I need to create a new array that adds together the first`5` elements then the next `5` elements, ect. so `1+2+3+4+5=15`, `6+7+8+9+10=40` `[15,40]`. How would i go about doing this?

Comment: Use [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks

Comment: Is it always going to be the first 5, then the next 5? What if it is a list with more than 10 elements. What then? Furthermore, the link provided by Artyer I think is incorrect for this example. Please show what you have tried. StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. You need to show your efforts in the form of a clear [mcve].

Comment: Well i have a code i'm running and it's used to analyze and plot out a set of values when they are all added together, I just have no clue how to ask the question, and showing my code probably wouldn't help. I guess i could post it though if you really want me to prove its not just a homework question or something.

Comment: @DB you actually did a really good job explaining what you are trying to do. If you tried to isolate the part of your code that attempts to do that slicing and explain what is happening around it, that would have been awesome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do something like :

```
>>> l1 =  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
>>> l2= [sum(l[n:n+5]) for n in range(0, len(l), 5)]
>>> l2
[15, 40]
```

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what i needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like that:

```
def sumEach5Element(input):
  o = []
  for i in range(0, len(input), 5):
    o.append(sum(input[i:i+5]))

  print(o)  

sumEach5Element([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this process :

```
arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
arr2 = [sum(arr1[:len(arr1)//2]), sum(arr1[len(arr1)//2:])]
print(arr2)
# output :
[15, 40]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution (I also considered an array which has a number of elements not divisible by 5):

```
my_array =  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
output_array = []
for i in range(len(my_array)/5): 
   tmp = my_array[i*5:(i+1)*5]
   output_array.append(sum(tmp))

# check if you can divide by 5
mod = len(my_array)%5
if mod > 0:
   output_array.append(sum(my_array[-mod::]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] 

def addList(sub): 
  result = sum(list(sub))
  return result

def breakTheList(arr, num):
    for i in range(0, len(arr), num):
        subDiv = arr[i:i + num]
        print(addList(subDiv))

breakTheList(arr, 5)
# 15 40
```

The above code will work with breaking the list into as many pieces as you like and add those pieces. Here is another example

```
breakTheList(arr, 4)
#10 26 19
```